# How Can I use the returned string (new feature of React v16.0.0) in the source tag of an image ex: <img src='returnedString' />?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fiber

I want to use the new feature on React v16.0.0 for returning a string, then use that string in

`<img src="returnedString" >`

**What is the current behavior?**

Well if I render my component in a
`<div > <MyComponent /> </div>`

I can see the string displayed on the screen (see attached screenshot), but my goal is to use that string in `<img src="returnedString" />`

**here is my code:**

```
// My component that returns strings
 class MyComponent extends Component {
   render(){

    switch (this.props.type) {
      case 'text':
        return this.props.json.data[this.props.Key]
        break
      case 'image':
        return this.props.json.data[this.props.Key]
        break
        default:
        return null
        break
    }
   }
 }

const UserComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* this displays the string on the page */}
      <MyComponent type='image' Key='avatar' desc='Abified image'  {...props} />

       {/* If I console.log this line I get <img src={[object object]} /> */}
       <img src={<MyComponent type='image' Key='avatar' desc='Abified image'  {...props} />} />
    </div>
   )
}

// Parent Component
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   json:[]
  }
 }

 // Fetching data from an api
 componentDidMount(){
   fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
       this.setState({json: json })
   })
 }

 render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <UserComponent {...this.state}/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

How Can I achieve that?

**What is the expected behavior?**

I want to use the returned string inside an

**Which versions of React ?**

React v16.0.0

**Did this work in previous versions of React?**

No because it's a new feature in React v16.0.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the image's `src` attribute dynamically, then use a plain javascript function instead of a component:

```
const getImageSrc = props => {
    switch (props.type) {
      case 'text':
      case 'image':
        return props.json.data[props.Key]
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from your component's `render` method like this:

```
<img src={ getImageSrc({...this.props, type: 'image', Key: 'avatar'}) } />
```

Comment: In my use case it needs to be a component. My implementation is currently returning a string if I render the component. ( I’ll add a screenshot to my question to clarify more)

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot, if I render `<MyComponent type='image' Key='avatar' />` the `returned string` is displayed on the screen. Is it a good practice to add your `getImageSrc` as a method of `<MyComponent />` then invoke it to get the `string`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, plain JavaScript function is the way to go

Comment: Follow up question, I want to gather all those props when `case 'image'` and add them to the state of `<MyComponent />` . I'm unable to do that because I'm unable to setState inside the render method

Comment: @AziCode not sure I understand but you could call `getImageSrc` from inside of `MyComponent` and set the state there. If that's not what you're looking for then feel free to open a new question with the details and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Because this

```
<MyComponent type='image' Key='avatar' desc='Abified image' />
```

is creating a **text node** in the dom.

But in this case

```
<img src={<MyComponent type='image' Key='avatar' desc='Abified image' {...props} />
```

your src attribute is getting a **react element object**.

You'll never get a string like that.
If you want to get your `src` dynamically, try something like this

```
const UserComponent = (props) => {
// calculate you src here
 const imageSrc = props.json.data['avatar'];
 return (
   <div> 
     <img src={ imageSrc } />
   </div> 
 )
}
```

Hope this helps.